# unity check color on collision Enter2d

Tags: unity, c#

So I am trying to figure out how to check the color of my sprite on collision 2d. 
I change my colors of sprites like this:

```
Color newColor = new Color(0.68f, 0.63f, 0.76f);
                    m_spriteRenderer.color = newColor;
```

and on the other script I have the OnCollision2d Function:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
```

acording to the color I want to delete the sprite or just add points.

Thanks,

Comment: Why did you delete your other account?

Comment: if(newColor==Color.red){//doSomething();}  ?

Comment: but how can i get the new Color from a other script

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in your monobehavior class:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    //Colors are written as 4 normalized values: (Red,Green,Blue,Alpha)
    if (other.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color == (1,0,0,1)) //alt: Color.red
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    {
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't do it for some reason.
This IF statement should automatically return false (do nothing) if something with a collider hits the game object this script is attached to, but doesn't have a SpriteRenderer component in the first place.